# How to communicate the element height from one directive to another directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get the div header height to set on content wrapper div with help of two directives. But I could not broadcast the height?

Is there anyway to achieve this?

**Angular**

```js
CommonDirectiveService.directive('headerHeight', function () {
    return {     
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {           
            scope.$broadcast('send', element[0].offsetHeight);
        }
    };
});

CommonDirectiveService.directive('setContentTop', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'headerHeight',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('send', function (e, data) {
                console.log(data);
                element.css('margin-top', data + 'px');
            });

        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="topPanel" header-height>
```

```html
<div class="masterWrapper content-wrapper" set-content-top>
   @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$rootScope` to broadcast non-nested events:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('send', element[0].offsetHeight);

$rootScope.$on('send', ..);
```

But I would add something like a callback:

```
CommonDirectiveService.directive('headerHeight', function () {
    return {     
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            listener: "&"
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {           
            scope.$watch(function() {
                return element[0].offsetHeight;
            }, function(val, oldVal) {
                if (val !== oldVal) {
                    scope.listener({ $height: val});
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

CommonDirectiveService.directive('setContentTop', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'headerHeight',
        scope: {
            margin: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch("margin", function(val) {
                console.log(val);
                element.css('margin-top', val + 'px');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<div id="topPanel" header-height listener="height = $height">

<div class="masterWrapper content-wrapper" set-content-top margin="height">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Or don't use a second directive at all:

```
<div id="topPanel" header-height listener="height = $height">

<div class="masterWrapper content-wrapper" ng-style="{ 'margin-top': height }">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but height is not updating in content-wrapper. how will get effected the height since both are different div's.  .